# Get parent id of placeholder container drag&drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get the placeholder id of my drag/drop elements.

on first drag&drop i could retrieve it, however the content comes from database and mostly will be pre-populated.

The problem i am facing now is, i cannot find the id of the binded drop container.

```js
$('document').ready(init);

function init() {
    $('[data-type]').bind('dragstart', function (event) {
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
    });

    // bind the dragover event on the board sections
    $('#header-container, #header-storage').bind('dragover', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //$(event.target).css({"background-color":"#AA0000"});
    });

    // bind the drop event on the board sections
    $('#header-container, #header-storage').bind('drop', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var notecard = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(notecard));
        var room = document.getElementById(event.target.id).parentNode;
        console.log(room);
        // Turn off the default behaviour
        // without this, FF will try and go to a URL with your id's name
        var $id = $(event.target).attr("data-element-id");
        alert('you dropped ' + notecard + ' into '+$id+' but into what container i do not know? In header-container or storage container?');

    });
}
```

```css
/* Customize container */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
}
.popover {
    min-width:300px;
    height:auto;
}
[data-type="column"] {
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2);
}
.row-hightlight {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    border: 1px solid #FFFF33;
    margin: 4px 0px;
}
[data-type="div"] {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(194, 200, 230, 1);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    max-width: 1022px;
}
.container-fluid {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #a4a4a4;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <!-- row start -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- col starts -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- panel starts -->
            <div id="storage" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Storage Container</h3>

                </div>
                <div id="header-storage" class="panel-body">
                    <!-- div Starts -->
                    <div class="clickMe " data-element-id="59" data-type="container" id="59" draggable="true">container</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- panel ends -->
        </div>
        <!-- col ends -->
        <!-- board starts -->
        <div id="header-container">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <!-- div Starts -->
                <div class="clickMe " data-element-id="43" data-type="div" id="43" draggable="true">
                    <!-- Container Starts -->
                    <div class="clickMe container-fluid" data-element-id="57" data-type="container" id="57" draggable="true">
                        <!-- div Starts -->
                        <div class="clickMe " data-element-id="52" data-type="div" id="52" draggable="true">
                            <!-- row Starts -->
                            <div class="row row-hightlight show-grid clickMe" data-element-id="60" data-type="row" id="60" draggable="true"></div>
                            <!-- row Ends -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- div Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- container Ends -->
                    <!-- Container Starts -->
                    <div class="clickMe container-fluid" data-element-id="54" data-type="container" id="54" draggable="true">
                        <!-- div Starts -->
                        <div class="clickMe " data-element-id="55" data-type="div" id="55" draggable="true">
                            <!-- row Starts -->
                            <div class="row row-hightlight show-grid clickMe" data-element-id="56" data-type="row" id="56" draggable="true"></div>
                            <!-- row Ends -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- div Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- container Ends -->
                    <!-- Container Starts -->
                    <div class="clickMe container-fluid" data-element-id="44" data-type="container" id="44" draggable="true">
                        <!-- row Starts -->
                        <div class="row row-hightlight show-grid clickMe" data-element-id="45" data-type="row" id="45" draggable="true">
                            <!-- column Starts -->
                            <div class="clickMe col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" data-element-id="51" data-type="column" id="51" draggable="true"></div>
                            <!-- column Ends -->
                            <!-- column Starts -->
                            <div class="clickMe col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" data-element-id="49" data-type="column" id="49" draggable="true">
                                <!-- row Starts -->
                                <div class="row row-hightlight show-grid clickMe" data-element-id="50" data-type="row" id="50" draggable="true">
                                    <!-- column Starts -->
                                    <div class="clickMe col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-element-id="47" data-type="column" id="47" draggable="true"></div>
                                    <!-- column Ends -->
                                    <!-- column Starts -->
                                    <div class="clickMe col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-element-id="48" data-type="column" id="48" draggable="true">
                                        <!-- div Starts -->
                                        <div class="clickMe " data-element-id="53" data-type="div" id="53" draggable="true"></div>
                                        <!-- div Ends -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- column Ends -->
                                    <!-- column Starts -->
                                    <div class="clickMe col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-element-id="46" data-type="column" id="46" draggable="true"></div>
                                    <!-- column Ends -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- row Ends -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- column Ends -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- row Ends -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- container Ends -->
                </div>
                <!-- div Ends -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- board ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- row ends -->
</div>
```

Comment: i was hoping to hide the code and show just the snippet (i do not wanted it to be that big (sorry if i abused the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `var $id = $(event.target).attr("data-element-id");` add:

```
alert( $(event.target).closest('#header-container, #header-storage').attr('id'));
```